# Error al intentar realizar la suma de un producto

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo las siguientes tablas

-Tabla Productos (Contiene el historial de todas las ventas de celulares)

-Tabla Tiendas (Contiene todas las tiendas a nivel mundial)

Existe N cantidad de celulares y marcas
Estoy intentando calcular la cantidad de estos productos que vende cada tienda:

Creé un case en el select para poder identificar con una `columna virtual` el tipo de producto y así lograr sumar dicha columna por tienda

Pero me da error en la setencia sum me dice que la columna `producto` no existe

Resultado que espero

| IdTienda | NombreTienda | Producto | Cantidad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TiendaA | CELULAR-IPHONE | 222 |
| 1 | TiendaA | CELULAR-SAMSUNG | 93 |
| 1 | TiendaA | CELULAR-ALCATEL | 0 |
| 2 | TiendaB | CELULAR-IPHONE | 32 |
| 2 | TiendaB | CELULAR-SAMSUNG | 123 |
| 2 | TiendaB | CELULAR-ALCATEL | 234 |
| 3 | TiendaC | CELULAR-IPHONE | 69 |
| 3 | TiendaC | CELULAR-SAMSUNG | 85 |
| 3 | TiendaC | CELULAR-ALCATEL | 33 |

```sql
select
    v.idTienda,
    v.tipo_producto,
    v.marca,
    t.nombre
    (select SUM(producto)),
    case 
        when tipo_producto = 'CELULAR' and marca = 'IPHONE'  then 'CELULAR-IPHONE'
        when tipo_producto = 'CELULAR' and marca = 'SAMSUNG' then 'CELULAR-SAMSUNGE'
        when tipo_producto = 'CELULAR' and marca = 'ALCATEL'  then 'CELULAR-ALCATEL'
        else 'No-Definido'
end as 'producto'
from dbo.VentasMovil as v
    INNER JOIN dbo.Tiendas as t on t.idTienda = v.idTienda
where producto != 'No-Definido'
```

Comment: Para poder escribir la consulta haría falta ver la estructura de las tablas, o al menos los campos relevantes para esta consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tenes es que no podes realizar consultas de agregacion sobre columnas generadas en tu misma query.

Lo que podes hacer es una subconsulta o directamente usar `GROUP BY`

Si el resultado que esperas es el de la tabla te sugiero probar con la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT v.idTienda, v.tipo_producto, v.marca, t.nombre, COUNT(*) AS Cantidad
 FROM from dbo.VentasMovil as v
    INNER JOIN dbo.Tiendas as t on t.idTienda = v.idTienda
where v.tipo_producto = 'CELULAR' AND v.marca IN ('IPHONE', 'SAMSUNG', 'ALCATEL')
GROUP BY v.idTienda, v.tipo_producto, v.marca, t.nombre
```

Fijate que en el WHERE solo restringi a los productos que queres mostrar, podes sacar esta condicion si necesitas mostrar todas las marcas y/o tipos

Si necesitas concatenada la marca con el nombre, podes usar la funcion de concatenacion de tu motor de base de datos (ej: en el caso de SQL Server es CONCAT y la usas como CONCAT(v.marca, CONCAT('-', t.nombre)))

Espero sirva!